# What is the proper way to get the DisplayColor out of the TrackExtension and into the MultiLineString.Style.Stroke.color?

Tags: colors, openlayers, gpx

Each trk in my gpx file contains

```
<extensions
 <gpxx:TrackExtension>
   <gpxx:DisplayColor>Red</gpxx:DisplayColor>
 </gpxx:TrackExtension>
</extensions>
```

with different values for gpxx:DisplayColor. I want to show each track in the color specified in the gpx file. Hence I need to get the color out of the (xml in) the gpx file and into the track style.

I tried

```
var trackColor = "black";
var gpx = new ol.source.Vector({   
  format: new ol.format.GPX({    
    readExtensions:
      function(feat, node)
      {
        var i, y;
        y = node.childNodes;
        for (i=0; i < y.length; i++)      
        {
          if (y[i].nodeName == "gpxx:TrackExtension")
          {
            trackColor = y[i].textContent;
          }
        }
      }
  })
});
```

This seems to be a kludge as it uses a loop and does not reference DisplayColor.

```
var track = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: gpx,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: trackColor,
      width: 3
    })
  })
});
```

The three trk elements have DisplayColors Red, DarkMagenta and Green, but all are shown in black.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the color into the feature on read to access it in a style function.
Something like this:

```js
var gpx = new ol.source.Vector({   
  format: new ol.format.GPX({    
    readExtensions: function(feat, node) {
      var i, y;
      y = node.childNodes;
      for (i=0; i < y.length; i++){
        if (y[i].nodeName == "gpxx:TrackExtension") {
          // save feature color
          feat.set('color', y[i].textContent);
        } else {
          feat.set('color', '#000');
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

then:

```js
var track = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: gpx,
  style: function (f, res) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        // get current feature color
        color: f.get('color'),
        width: 3
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with a small improvement. The line "feat.set('color', '#000');" should be moved to before the loop.